# Output jquery/ajax data in loop as HTML to div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, for-loop

I have retrieved some data from a servlet and now want to output is as HTML to div called "showArticles" and have same html chunk for each value. However, it only outputs one value. So I have:

```
|Article Title.   |
|Article content. |
```

I want there be a number of such htmls.
Thank you in advance.

The AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "LoadArticlesByTag",
        dataType : 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            b_sub_tag:option_value
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        },
        success : function(data){
           var data1=data[0], data2=data[1];
           for(var i=0;i<data1.length;i++){
            outputToDiv(data1,i);
           }
        }

    });


function outputToDiv(data1,i) {                
            $('#showArticles').html(                
            "<article class='one_quarter'>"+
                "<figure><img src='images/demo/32x32.gif' width='32' height='32' alt=''></figure>"+
                "<strong>"+data1[i]["name"]+"</strong>"+
                "<p>"+data1[i]["content"]+"</p>"+
                "<p class='more'><a href='#'>Read More &raquo;</a></p>"

                );
        }
```

Comment: I suggest you change `outputToDiv` to take a single argument, and call it as `outputToDiv(data1[i])`. That way you don't have to keep repeating the array index. Also, use the syntax `data.name` and `data.content` instead of array-style syntax;the latter should only be used for numeric arrays or when the property is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, `.html()` *replaces* the content of the target selector. Try using `.append()`.

```
$('#showArticles').append(...)
```

Always remember to [check the docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) to understand how functions work when they don't do as you expect.

Comment: Hello Christian. Thank you very much. It worked. I only started using jquery yesterday, so did not get around so much.How could I clear what was outputted so that only new selections will be displayed? I have a select there. Thank you.

Comment: In your ajax success function, right before the `for` loop, clear it there like so: `$('#showArticles').html('');`

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding the content on `#showArticles` every time you call `outputToDiv` because of the use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/). You need to either add it to the start using [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or the end using [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) if you want to retain the current contents..

```
$('#showArticles').append(
     "<article class='one_quarter'>"+
     "<figure><img src='images/demo/32x32.gif' width='32' height='32' alt=''></figure>"+
     "<strong>"+data1[i]["name"]+"</strong>"+
     "<p>"+data1[i]["content"]+"</p>"+
     "<p class='more'><a href='#'>Read More &raquo;</a></p>");
```